# Error 160 WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK 2.3 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, sdk

When I am trying to build my project (inherited code) on Visual Studio 2013, I receive the following error:
**Error 160 WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK. Please make sure Windows Azure SDK 2.3 is installed.**

The error points to the file **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets** located at
**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3.**

I have installed Azure SDK 2.3 from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42317
in folder
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.3.**
and added it to the system path in my windows machine.
Nevertheless, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

## NuGet package

Try to install local nuget package for project - this is the way recommended by Microsoft.
Depending on what you exacly need, check what you can install:

- [Windows Azure Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)
- [All Azure packages at NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Azure%20sdk)

## Azure SDK

Install Windows Azure tools for Visual Studio

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff687127.aspx

and restart Visual Studio for sure.

You should see it in `TOOLS->Extensions and updates` on screen like in below
[image]

Comment: As per the article when I choose File, New, Project. From Installed Templates choose either the Visual Basic or Visual C# node, and then choose the Cloud node, I dont see 'Get Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET' template, instead I see 'Windows Azure cloud services'. When I click on ok, I dont see 'Azure tools' tab.

Comment: There are more than 100 packages at the Nuget links you provided. Do you want me to install all of them? Do you want me to try in this sequence as you mentioned? (1) NuGet Package (2) Azure SDK?

Comment: What you exactly have to run on Azure? Some connection to Azure Storage or more? What namespaces you're missing in your project? Last time i was using Azure Storage and `Windows Azure Storage` was sufficient for me.